# ¿como puedo poner estas imagenes en un fila, sea responsive?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

tengo un problema, cuando se muestra la web en mi pc, el tamaño de la seccion de noticias, se supone que deben ver un fila de 4 imagenes, pero solo me muestra 2 filas, donde la primera fila son las tres imagenes, y la segunda fila aparece la 4 imagen,
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
      <div class="text-center mx-auto pb-4 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.1s" >
        <a href="noticias.html" class="btn py-3 px-5 animated slideInRight">
          <h1 class="display-5 mb-4">Noticias</h1></a>
      </div>
 <div class="center">
    <section id="content">
      <div class="row  row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3 g-4">
              <div class="col" style="max-width: 300px">
                <div class="card h-100">
                  <img 
                    src="img/portal_alto_mirasol.png"
                    style="max-width: 300px"
                    class="card-img-top logo-1 col-4"
                    alt="..."
                  />
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Portal Altos de Mirasol II</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">
                      Asesoría a la Fiscalización Técnica de Obras DS-49 "Portal
                      Altos de Mirasol II", Puerto Montt.
                    </p>
                    <p class="card-text">
                      <small class="text-muted">En Ejecucion...</small>
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col" style="max-width: 300px">
                <div class="card h-100">
                  <img
                    src="img/vista_cordillera.png"
                    style="max-width: 300px"
                    class="card-img-top col-4"
                    alt="..."
                  />
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Proyecto Vista Cordillera</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">
                      Asesoría a la Fiscalización Técnica de Obras DS-49 "Proyecto
                      Vista Cordillera", Puerto Montt.
                    </p>
                    <p class="card-text">
                      <small class="text-muted">En Ejecucion...</small>
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col" style="max-width: 300px">
                <div class="card h-100">
                  <img
                    src="img/escuela_compu.png"
                    style="max-width: 300px"
                    class="card-img-top col-4"
                    alt="..."
                  />
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Escuela Rural Compu</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">
                      Asesoría a la Inspección Fiscal de la obra reposición escuela
                      rural Compu, comuna Quellón.
                    </p>
                    <p class="card-text">
                      <small class="text-muted">En Ejecucion...</small>
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col" style="max-width: 300px">
                <div class="card h-100">
                  <img
                    src="img/casa_pauly.png"
                    style="max-width: 300px"
                    class="card-img-top col-4"
                    alt="..."
                  />
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">
                      Inspección Fiscal Conservación Casa Pauly
                    </h5>
                    <p class="card-text">
                      Asesoría a la Inspección Fiscal Conservación Casa Pauly,
                      Puerto Montt.
                    </p>
                    <p class="card-text">
                      <small class="text-muted">En Ejecucion...</small>
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

aca esta el css cada vez que aumento el width a 100%, me afecta en tamaño pequeño, como se demuestra en la imagen:(, eso me sucede cuando solo modifico esas propiedades, primera foto me resulta bien todo centrado en tamaño pequeño, pero cuando aumento a 100%, el tamaño de foto me queda bien me junta las 4 fotos, en una fila. :(

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
   .center{
    width: 75%;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
```

Comment: Puedes crear un [repro] en la pregunta misma a través de un snippet (con el botón que indica `<>`). Si lo haces, no olvides agregar la librería de Bootstrap.

Comment: no se como es, pero es algo asi, [enlace](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/standard/extended/news-feed/), el News aggregator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que le estás dando un ancho fijo a cada tarjeta con la propiedad **`max-width: 300px`**, de la cual no se tomará en cuenta el ancho que toma los **`col`** dentro del **`row`**, es por eso que las tarjetas no se estiran del todo bien cuando la resolución de pantalla es cada vez más pequeña. A cada tarjeta, le apliqué las siguientes clases:

```
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6"> <!-- Este es el nuevo cambio para cada tarjeta -->
      <div class="card h-100">
        <img 
          src="https://i.imgur.com/rc4Zbbw.jpg"
          style="width: 100%;"
          class="card-img-top logo-1 col-4"
          alt="..."
        />
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Portal Altos de Mirasol II</h5>
          <p class="card-text">
            Asesoría a la Fiscalización Técnica de Obras DS-49 "Portal
            Altos de Mirasol II", Puerto Montt.
          </p>
          <p class="card-text">
            <small class="text-muted">En Ejecucion...</small>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

En donde:

```
// col-lg-3 => en el ancho 'lg' de la pantalla ocupará las 4 tarjetas en 1 fila
// col-sm-6 => en el ancho 'sm' de la pantalla ocupará solo 2 tarjetas en 2 filas
```

Y para que esto funcione, tu clase **`row`**, que encierra las 4 tarjetas, tendría que estar de la siguiente manera:

```
<div class="row g-4">
  // ...
</div>
```

Ahora para arreglar lo de las imágenes, apliqué los siguientes cambios para que ocupe siempre el 100% del ancho de la tarjeta y no haya espacio de sobra:

```
<img
  src="https://i.imgur.com/rc4Zbbw.jpg"
  style="width: 100%;" // Este es el nuevo cambio
  class="card-img-top col-4"
  alt="..."
/>
```

Y también en tu clase **`.center`** no es necesario que apliques la propiedad **`width: 75%;`**, esto solo hará que las tarjetas estén mal posicionadas, les di las siguientes propiedades para que tenga un mejor resultado:

```
.center{
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
```

Tu código final sería el siguiente:

```css
.center{
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="text-center mx-auto wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.1s" >
  <a href="noticias.html" class="btn py-3 px-5 animated slideInRight">
    <h1 class="display-5 mb-4">Noticias</h1>
  </a>
</div>
 <div class="center">
    <section id="content">
      <div class="row g-4">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
          <div class="card h-100">
            <img 
              src="https://i.imgur.com/rc4Zbbw.jpg"
              style="width: 100%;"
              class="card-img-top logo-1 col-4"
              alt="..."
            />
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Portal Altos de Mirasol II</h5>
              <p class="card-text">
                Asesoría a la Fiscalización Técnica de Obras DS-49 "Portal
                Altos de Mirasol II", Puerto Montt.
              </p>
              <p class="card-text">
                <small class="text-muted">En Ejecucion...</small>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
          <div class="card h-100">
            <img
              src="https://i.imgur.com/rc4Zbbw.jpg"
              style="width: 100%;"
              class="card-img-top col-4"
              alt="..."
            />
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Proyecto Vista Cordillera</h5>
              <p class="card-text">
                Asesoría a la Fiscalización Técnica de Obras DS-49 "Proyecto
                Vista Cordillera", Puerto Montt.
              </p>
              <p class="card-text">
                <small class="text-muted">En Ejecucion...</small>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
          <div class="card h-100">
            <img
              src="https://i.imgur.com/rc4Zbbw.jpg"
              style="width: 100%;"
              class="card-img-top col-4"
              alt="..."
            />
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Escuela Rural Compu</h5>
              <p class="card-text">
                Asesoría a la Inspección Fiscal de la obra reposición escuela
                rural Compu, comuna Quellón.
              </p>
              <p class="card-text">
                <small class="text-muted">En Ejecucion...</small>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
          <div class="card h-100">
            <img
              src="https://i.imgur.com/rc4Zbbw.jpg"
              style="width: 100%;"
              class="card-img-top col-4"
              alt="..."
            />
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">
                Inspección Fiscal Conservación Casa Pauly
              </h5>
              <p class="card-text">
                Asesoría a la Inspección Fiscal Conservación Casa Pauly,
                Puerto Montt.
              </p>
              <p class="card-text">
                <small class="text-muted">En Ejecucion...</small>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

En el siguiente [**enlace**](https://codepen.io/christopher-ps/pen/eYKLbON) podrás ver mejor los resultados.

Comment: ah, okey, vale pa gracias, una duda es mejor dividir por class, o aplicarlas a una sola clase, o depende?

Comment: Puedes dividirlo mediante las clases de bootstrap (recomendado) o también con los estilos css, a tu gusto.

Comment: ah, okey pa gracias, me resolviste mi problema :), gracias!!

Comment: Un gusto poder ayudarle, saludos!